# Error when applying values to an object

Tags: java, constructor

I need some help with this java code, i seem to get stuck at the object vara var = new vara("banan","12.5","5"). I thought since i created a constructor in class vara with three  arguments String,double and int it would be fine to call for them in the test class and get the result i want but i get an error stating that constructor vara in class vara cannot be applied to given types. And it says it requires a string, a double and an  int. But i have provided these so what is the problem?? id be thankful for any kind of help, im stuck with this for 4  days now and i just cant see any light in the tunnel.

```
import java.lang.String;

public class Vara {              

//Deklarerar variabler 

private String name; 
private double price; 
private int antal;

//tildela konstruktorer för de deklarerade variablerna 
public Vara (String name, int antal, double price) { 
this.name = name;
this.antal = antal;
this.price = price; 
} // slut constructor

 public void setName(String name)  {  
 this.name = name; } 

public void  setPrice (double price) { 
this.price = price; } 

public void setAntal (int antal)  {  
this.antal = antal;  }

public String getName() {    
return this.name;} 

public double getPrice() {   
return this.price; } 

public int getAntal() {    
return this.antal; }     
}

//testklassen ska stå som en egen klass
class Test {    
    public void main(String[] args){ 
    }   
Vara var = new Vara("Banan","12.5","5") {

        @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
var.setName("Banan");
    }  
        @Override
public void setPrice (double price) {
var.setPrice("12.5");  
}
        @Override
public void setAntal (int antal) {
var.setAntal("5");


System.out.println("Namnet är " +var.getName() +" priset är " +var.getPrice() +" och antalet är "+var.getAntal() );// här slutar system.out

}// slut main  
}

// slut Test klass
```

Comment: double quote enclosed anything(including numbers) are Strings in java

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the constructor with wrong parameters :

```
Vara var = new Vara("Banan","12.5","5")
```

is not  what your constructor expects :

```
public Vara (String name, int antal, double price)
```

You are passing three `String` literal to the constructor when it expects a `String`,`int`,`double` **in specified order**. Anything enclosed in `""` is a `String` literal.

Replace with :

```
Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5,12.5);
```

> "Banan" ---> It is a String literal.
>
> 12.5 ---> double by default , 12.5f is float.
>
> 5 ---> int by default , 5l is long.

You need to do the same thing while invoking the setter methods.

Comment: i changed it but it still doesnt work.... :/
Isnt the correct one now:

Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5,12,5);

Comment: You have specified extra comma !

Comment: `Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5,12.5);` you have used a comma in place of dot (.) for double value 12.5

Comment: now its telling me i dont have a main class...what exactly creates that problem... :/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes from the last two arguments to constructor:

```
Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5,12.5);
```

**Reason:** If you enclose between double quotes then it is treated as `String` by Java and not double or int. And as your constructor does not accept three String arguments it gives error.

Same is the issue with the setter methods that you are calling on the `var` object.

the `setAntal(int antal)` needs an `int` argument but you are passing `String`. Hence remove double quotes while calling setter method too.

```
var.setAntal(5);
var.setPrice(12.5);
```

Also when you send the tree arguments to the constructor, then you do not need to call the setter method for setting the same values again.

**Running Code:**

```
public class Vara {              

    //Deklarerar variabler 

    private String name; 
    private double price; 
    private int antal;

    //tildela konstruktorer för de deklarerade variablerna 
    public Vara (String name, int antal, double price) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.antal = antal;
        this.price = price; 
    } // slut constructor

    public void setName(String name)  {  
        this.name = name; } 

    public void  setPrice (double price) { 
        this.price = price; } 

    public void setAntal (int antal)  {  
        this.antal = antal;  }

    public String getName() {    
        return this.name;} 

    public double getPrice() {   
        return this.price; } 

    public int getAntal() {    
        return this.antal; }     
}

//testklassen ska stå som en egen klass
class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5, 12.5);
        System.out.println("Namnet är " +var.getName() +" priset är " +var.getPrice() +" och antalet är "+var.getAntal() );// här slutar system.out

    }
}
```

To point out some errors:

- Your `main` method must be **static**
- main method ended as soon as it starts and code must be inside the main method.

For others compare my code with yours. I would recommend you to see some basic java tutorials.

Comment: you guys are amazing, thanks..i removed the double quotes and did everything you said so as far as the methods is concerned it seems ok but still get error with the Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5,12.5);.

Comment: I have pasted the working code. Copy that and execute. There were multiple issues with the code. I will try to incorporate that in the answer.

Comment: Please note that the code must be in a file called `Vara.java` and not `Test.java`.

Comment: I changed my file name by mistake. :) Will change it. Thanks.

Comment: @UwePlonus Actually I made the Test class public by mistake. Hence the file name change. Have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are calling your constructor with 3 `String` parameters:

```
Vara var = new Vara("banan", "12.5", "5");
```

As you have only defined a constructor which takes a `String`, an `int` and a `double` you have to remove the quotation marks:

```
Vara var = new Vara("banan", 12.5, 5);
```

Also this will not work as you now supply a `double` to the `int` parameter and vice versa. So either you have to change your constructor to

```
public Vara (String name, double price, int antal)
```

or change your call to

```
Vara var = new Vara("banan", 5, 12.5);
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive, vara should be Vara

Comment: @Trisha Thanks, I copied some code from the question without checking this.

Answer (score 0):

As you declared constructor of the class as `public Vara (String name, int antal, double price)` , so at you should call create an object of this class is as follow

```
Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5,12.5);
```